# Wireless networks keeps prompting password on every distro

Tags: linux, wifi

I had been using Windows for a while but made the switch over to Linux. I thought I'd go with Elementary OS. I got a  problem soon enough: when I tried to connect to a wireless network, it would process the information given and then prompt for the network's password once again. This only happens with networks that require a password.

I then tried Linux Mint. Same problem.
Then Kali Linux. Same problem. But with Kali, during installation it asked me for home network and password which I gave and which it connected. However, it fails to connect to any other network that asks for a password. I've tried using WIXD, making Wi-Fi available to all users, etc, but no luck. I know this sounds vague but any help would be really appreciated. I need this working asap.